# Is asking opinion-based questions "need good luck (i.e. Faster than close vote)" to get answers?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

I'm just curious to know why don't hide or remove opinion-based questions from this site, if these types of questions are forbidden.

To be honest, sometimes I find some closed opinion-based questions have good opinion-based answers:)

I just feel asking opinion-based questions need to have good luck : if you're good luck, you got answers before close votes. (Sorry for poor description! I'm not encouraging breaking rules, just my personal feeling only!)

Comment: We do remove them. You just don't see the ones that get removed because, you know, they've been removed.

Comment: @BoltClock worth adding that deleted _answered_ questions are [heavier penalized by question ban algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168835/165773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, opinion-based questions can have good opinionated answers, depending on one's definition of "good". But they are just that: opinions. And opinionated Q&As simply don't belong on Stack Exchange.

And frankly, you don't need a whole lot of luck at all to get answers to opinion-based questions. Most opinion-based questions get closed and removed quite swiftly these days, but some of them can take a while. And those do attract opinionated answers. And sometimes, those opinionated answers generate way too much discussion in the comments before the question itself gets enough of the right attention to be shut down.

Besides, you shouldn't be thinking of this in terms of getting lucky. Saying it takes luck to get an answer to a question that doesn't belong on the site is like saying it takes luck to get away with lying to someone. Sure, you might be able to get away with it for a while, and/or reap some short-term benefits. But in the long run, you're just doing harm to everyone involved. (In the case of Stack Exchange, this refers to content that threatens to dilute the overall content quality of the site.)